# Google Sheets: How can I test if there are any time-driven triggers assigned to sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

**Short version:** I want to output text in cell B12 if a time-driven trigger has been set for the sheet. I am using a free Google account (not G Suite). `If you don't want to read my long version, you can skip to (2) at the end of long version and then to code.`

**Long version:**  I created some digital paperwork for our employees. We need to backup these sheets as we cannot rely solely on the Google Drive storage. I was dumbfounded when I realized that the .gsheet files that are pulled down when using Google Drive Backup and Sync are not actual backup files - they are just a file containing a URL which points to the cloud location. So, I figured out how to write a script [*function backup()*] to make a copy of the sheet as an XLSX file and put it in another folder in GDrive. That is done and works great when I combined it with a time-driven trigger that is installed programmatically.

Next comes the problem. There is a sheet that is named TEMPLATE. Every morning, the **supervisors make a copy of the TEMPLATE sheet**. They then use the copy to record their daily work. Every job needs a separate sheet. Herein lies the problem - time-driven triggers are not copied when you copy a sheet. So every new sheet that is made (by copying the TEMPLATE) does not have the time-driven trigger installed.

**My solution that does not work:** To programmatically install time-driven triggers on a newly copied sheet, authorization is required first. To solve this, I created another script that creates a custom menu. In that custom menu the user can click a button that runs the another script I created onOpen(). When selected, onOpen() creates the time-driven trigger programmatically but first asks for authorization. This means on every single job (new sheet created by copying TEMPLATE), someone has to click through the authorization steps to allow the script to run. We run multiple jobs per day. This is a hassle for my employees. I am trying as hard as I can to work around this issue.

(1) I don't think there is any way around the authorization, but if anyone knows any way, PLEASE let me know!

**(2) I do not want to require the users to remember to click the custom menu and then the function:**

- `I want B12 to designate if the user needs to access the custom menu to run the function.`

  - `So B12 would have the following text written to it "Must choose at top: Custom Menu/Initialize Backend" **IF** a trigger has not been created.`

My limited understanding is that the code below works when run straight from the script editor because it bypasses the limitations of the built in function **onEdit(e)**.

When I edit the sheet within the defined range that the code lists, nothing happens because **onEdit(e)** will not call **ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers()**.

I have spent days researching other solutions, and now I am hoping some kind soul will lend their knowledge. Maybe I can take an entirely different approach? I sure hope this is possible.

For clarity, I hope we can find an answer to what I laid out in (2). But, below is what I want to do stated simply from start to finish. If you can think of a different way to approach this altogether, please let me know:

- End user makes copy of TEMPLATE Google Sheet to use for the day.
- Scripts in the TEMPLATE get copied too, so end user does not have to do anything else.
- Later that day, scripts make a copy of the Google Sheet and saves it as an XLSX file in another Google Drive folder at specified time.
- I use Google Drive Backup and Sync to download all the XLSX files to my comptuer, and then I use CMD Robocopy to transfer to server on a schedule.

```html
function onEdit(e) 
{
  var editRange = { // D2:H8
    top : 2,
    bottom : 8,
    left : 4,
    right : 8
  };

  // Exit if we're out of range
  var thisRow = e.range.getRow();
  if (thisRow < editRange.top || thisRow > editRange.bottom) return;

  var thisCol = e.range.getColumn();
  if (thisCol < editRange.left || thisCol > editRange.right) return;

  // We're in range
  var ss = e.range.getSheet();

  // onEdit won't call ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers() CAN'T MAKE THIS WORK
  if (ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers() < 1) {
    ss.getRange("B12").setValue('Must choose at top: Custom Menu/Initialize Backend');
  }
  else
  {
     ss.getRange("B12").setValue('');
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? In your ideal goal, you want to set the time-driven trigger by a script with only the simple trigger without the installable trigger. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I think that my understanding of my latest comment was not correct?

Comment: @Tanaike I edited my title and the beginning of the post to say "time-driven trigger".
My ideal goal is this:
(1) TEMPLATE sheet is copied daily.
(2) Copies retain all the necessary scripting of the TEMPLATE so that they can automatically be copied later in the day as an XLSX file to another folder
(3) The Time-driven trigger that runs the script to make the XLSX file needs to be on the copied file. 

All I want is XLSX copies of all sheet files created automatically so I can back them up to our server.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand whether my understanding is correct. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this. If I could correctly understand your situation. I would like to think of about the issue and solution.

Comment: @Tanaike to answer your question directly, I am not sure. I have read the Google documentation on Installable Triggers but I do not understand 100%. It looks like those may only be for G Suite accounts? 
I have written a script to programmatically install the time-driven trigger, but I am not sure this is the same thing as an "installable trigger". It looks like the answer may be yes to your question, but I really am looking for any way to get this done. I just want to have XLSX copies of all Google sheets created automatically, so I can back those up to a server.

Comment: Thank you for replying. The installable trigger can be used with "a free Google account". About `I have written a script to programmatically install the time-driven trigger, but I am not sure this is the same thing as an "installable trigger".`, I think that it is the installable trigger. When I read your question, I had thought that you might want to make the user set the time-driven trigger for running the script of "backup" after the template Spreadsheet was copied.

Answer (score 2):

#### Goal:

- Automatically convert/backup all Google sheet files to xlsx files daily.

#### Issue:

- Attempting to call `ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers()` from a simple trigger.  Simple trigger doesn't have enough authorization to get project triggers.

#### Solution:

- Use `propertiesService` to store trigger id, when created. If not present in properties, display a banner.

#### Snippet:

- onEdit:

```
var triggerId = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('tid');
if (!triggerId) {
    //or display a banner
    //@see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57480181
    ss.getRange("B12").setValue('Must choose at top: Custom Menu/Initialize Backend');
}
```

- Initialize Backend:

```
var tid = ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunc')
    .timeBased()
    .everyDays(1)
    .create()
    .getUniqueId();
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty({'tid':tid});
```

#### Alternative Approaches:

- If all the files are in a single drive or if someone has edit access to all the files, you can create backups using `DriveApp` in a single script file(instead of multiple projects).

  - This would be the preferred method.
  - If it's not in a single drive, This can also be accomplished if supervisors make a copy in a folder with edit access to a common user(a user who has access to all files)
- Publish a add-on. This will prevent multiple script projects and multiple authorizations and limit quota usage.

#### To Read:

- [Properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties)
- [Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#newTrigger(String))
- [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFilesByType(String))
- [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/watch)
- [Add ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/overview)
- [Quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You must perform an edit within the range.
Also you must supply the spreadsheet id as shown below in the code.
You also have to run the installAnOnEditTrigger() function and name the function "xxOnEdit" also include the e paramenter to hold the event object.

```
function xxOnEdit(e) {
  var editRange = {top : 2,bottom : 8,left : 4,right : 8};
  if(e.range.rowStart<editRange.top || e.range.rowStart>editRange.bottom || e.range.columnStart<editRange.left||e.range.columnStart>editRange.right) return;
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if (ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().length==0) {
    sh.getRange("B12").setValue('Must choose at top: Custom Menu/Initialize Backend');
  }else{
    sh.getRange("B12").setValue('Scripts: ' + ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().length);
  }
}

function installAnOnEditTrigger() {
  var trgA=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  var found=false;
  for(var i=0;i<trgA.length;i++) {
    if(trgA[i].getHandlerFunction()=="xxOnEdit") {
      found=true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(!found) {//This prevents you from creating more than one installable trigger
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("xxOnEdit").forSpreadsheet("SpreadsheetId").onEdit().create();
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it did not work either. Could you give me a little more info with the installable trigger bit you mentioned? How would I do that?

Comment: Try my modified version.

Comment: No dice. I appreciate the help though.

Comment: Well I guess I'll have to dig into it a little more and do some debugging and see why it won't work.  I'll get back with you soon.

Comment: I just checked the latest code and if you're doing  an edit inside of that range then you will see data in B12.

Comment: Sorry I had to add some last minute instructions.