# onEdit script does not start for users under anonymous access

Tags: google-apps-script, anonymous-access

it's my 1st public question, hope I'm clear enough.

Here is the context:

- I have created a spreadsheet as a template, including an "onEdit script"
- I have made a copy of the spreadsheet created above, editable by everyone who has the link
- when I open this copy and :
- edit it, under my account (as owner), script works :)
- edit it, under another google account script works :)
- edit it, from an anonymous access, I can edit the sheet, but the script does not work :(

I have already read many posts like https://support.google.com/docs/thread/10422866?hl=en&msgid=10677830,
also tried this : https://support.google.com/docs/thread/41307278?hl=en&msgid=41569467. Got the same difference related to user access. :(

In fact, I need to share sheets with publics (without expecting Google account) and, because they are invited to, I need to determine which cells they may have edited.

Any idea will be greatly appreciated ! :)

Comment: Hi Course, welcome to SO. Please strongly consider posting a MRE (stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with snippets of both HTML and CSS (and JS if applicable or other lang.) so we can better help you thank you.

Comment: It does work, but without access to `ui`. Show your script+ view> executions

Comment: Related [Google Apps Script toast messages don't appear for anonymous editors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57480181/1595451)

Comment: Please show your script, as mentioned above, there are possibly workarounds, but without knowing what exactly you are trying to do, it is hard to help.